# input shape of convolutional neural network in keras

Tags: python, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a image classifier using cnn. My images are of (256,256) pixel size.

What will happen if i train the cnn by setting the input shape as (64,64) or (128,128), since (256,256) will take a lot of time to process?

Answer (score 0):

It will throw an error. You can resize you images with cv2.resize() or you can put the right input shape in your cnn layer and then put a maxpooling layer to reduce the number of parameters.

Comment: NO it is working and showing result, so i am confused that, what is happening inside if we reduce the original size.

Comment: NO it is not throwing error and it works. I am confused that whether this will reduce accuracy or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image size is same as the size your `Input` layer is expecting. Classification architectures, in general, are not flexible to the spatial dimensions of your input. So, that is important. Otherwise you will get a shape mismatch error.

In case you want to change the input shape of your model, that is possible to do. It's hard to say exactly how it will affect your classification. You have to, probably, also tune your CNN filters so that the filters are not bigger than your feature maps. Otherwise that might downgrade your performance. But you can try that out and see what happens.

Comment: I thought that a reduced input shape will take information in a smaller part of the image. is it true ??

Comment: No. That's not how it works. The network still looks at the entire image you input. For different inputs, it gets to look at the features at different scales. This can be good or bad for the prediction, depending on your problem and the dataset.

Comment: I have no idea how your data or network looks. So it is hard to suggest anything more concrete. Try to put more details in your post when you ask questions.